# Powershell get computer name and add to AD group

Tags: powershell, active-directory

I am trying to utilize Powershell to get the computer name it’s currently running on and then add that computer to a security group and I’m stuck.

Forcing myself to learn Powershell better and got this from a co-worker but not sure how to edit it for my needs. This script will be used to run after a certain package has been installed to grant access. Here is what I have so far:

```
param(
    [string[]]$mname,
    [string[]]$gname
)

foreach($m in $mname.split(','))
{
    $mobj = get-adcomputer $m
    foreach($g in $gname.split(','))
    {
        Add-ADGroupMember "GROUP_NAME" -Members $mobj
    }
}
```

ERROR:
You cannot call a method on a null-valued expression.
At C:\Scripts\Add-MachineToCollectionGroup.ps1:6 char:15
+ foreach($m in $mname.split(','))

Comment: Why are you splitting on the comma? What does your data look like?

Comment: How are you calling the script? Looks like you forgot to pass an argument to `-mname`

Comment: If you like to learn Powershell you might start to learn the basics of Powershell in a more structured way  ... per example with a free of charge video course from Microsoft. [Getting Started with Microsoft PowerShell](https://mva.microsoft.com/en-us/training-courses/getting-started-with-powershell-3-0-jump-start-8276?l=r54IrOWy_2304984382)

Answer (score 0):

Just add your groupname at the top, also if you aren't running Powershell 5 you may need to change `Add-ADGroupMember $groupobj -Members $computerobj` to be `Add-ADGroupMember $groupobj -Member $computerobj` I think they changed that.

Also add `-whatif` to the end of the last line to test it (It'll tell you what it would have done without the whatif).

Oh also you will need to run this from an account that has AD access to add the machine to the group and the computer must have the activedirectory module installed.

```
$Groupname = "ENTER GROUP NAME HERE"

$computerobj = Get-ADComputer $env:COMPUTERNAME
$groupobj = Get-ADGroup $Groupname

Add-ADGroupMember $groupobj -Members $computerobj -WhatIf
```